# CoreData use NSMangedObject multiple

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'd like to use a NSManagedObject in 2 functions, but don't want to create 2 NSManagedObjects. How can I use one NSManagedObject in 2 Functions? I'd like to save data in this 2 methods in 2 different attributes.

Object: var newNote = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Note", inManagedObjectContext: self.context!) as Note

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Core Data, it's a basic Swift question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is how to pass an NSManagedObject as a parameter of a function. You do it like this:

First, declare functions in your class that takes the NSManagedObject subclass as a parameter.

```
func someFunc(note: Note) {
    // Do something
    note.someProperty = someValue
}
func someFunc2(note: Note) {
    // Do something
}
```

Then create an instance of Note and pass that instance as a parameter for both of those functions.

```
var newNote = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Note", inManagedObjectContext: self.context!) as Note

someFunc(newNote)
someFunc2(newNote)
```